# applying count() across multiple columns in a table referencing the same foreign key

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys, union

I'm trying to get group counts for music genres on weekly top songs list, where the table for the billboard top songs has multiple foreign keys all to the song's primary key `song_id`.

E.g.: over the past 4 weeks 10 rock songs, 12 pop songs, 2 country songs, etc. appeared somewhere on the weekly top billboard songs.

`song` table:
| song_id | song_name | genre |
| -------- | -------- | ------|
| 1   | ab  | pop |
| 2   | cd   | rock |
| 3   | ef   | rap |
| ...   | ...   | ... |

and the `weekly_top_chart` table:

| bboard_id | song1_id | song2_id | song3_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 2 | 8 | 12 | 4 |
| ... | .... | ... | ... |

I've tried using `UNION` on `INNER JOIN` statements for each `song#_id` column to `song_id`

```
SELECT count(s1.genre) AS gcnt 
FROM weekly_top_chart wtc 
INNER JOIN song s1 ON wtc.song1_id = s1.song_id
GROUP BY s1.genre
UNION
SELECT count(s2.genre) AS gcnt 
FROM weekly_top_chart wtc 
INNER JOIN song s2 ON wtc.song2_id = s2.song_id
GROUP BY s2.genre;
```

However the result I get is simply:

|  | gcnt |
| --- | --- |
|  | 2 |
|  | 1 |

I've also tried chaining `INNER JOIN`s but then I can't get the totals across all columns

```
SELECT s1.genre, count(s1.genre), s2.genre, count(s2.genre)
FROM musicdb.weekly_top_chart wtc 
INNER JOIN musicdb.song s1 ON wtc.song1_id = s1.song_id
INNER JOIN musicdb.song s2 ON wtc.song2_id = s2.song_id
GROUP BY s1.genre, s2.genre;
```